# git add submodule of remote

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule in a git remote repository. I cloned the repository before the remote submodule was created.

## How can I add the submodule of the remote repository?

I tried the following:

```
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

and

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

But none of those commands worked—there is no .gitmodules file.

The remote has a `.gitmodules` file with information about the submodule. In the remote repository:

```
$ git submodule
+79444cf2aaa9279b4838f52b81cc40ad3f116771 Appendix
```

The `.gitmodules` file was added to the repository as evidenced by:

```
$ git status .gitmodules
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

If `.gitmodules` had not been committed this command would have stated that it was untracked.

Comment: *"I have a submodule in a git remote repository."* Did you commit the addition of that submodule? Does your local repository have that (or a later) commit checked out?

Comment: @cdhowie I've updated my question to include information about the remote submodule.

Comment: But was this `.gitmodules` file ever committed?

Comment: @cdhowie, yes. Please see question edit.

Comment: Alright.  What if you run the same status command on the local repository?

Comment: @cdhowie Ok, now I'm embarrassed. Apparently, I hadn't pulled from the remote since adding the remote. Duh!

Comment: That's what I thought might have happened when I said *"Does your local repository have that (or a later) commit checked out?"*  :)  I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `.gitmodules` file does not yet exist in your local repository.  Make sure that this file has been committed in the remote repository and that you have since pulled this commit to your local repository.